# Is it good to add code in separate file in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am learning ASP.NET. I have just started and found there is an option to add code in a separate file.

What are the advantages and dis-advantages of adding code in a separate file i.e `.cs` file with every `.aspx` web form, beside compilation errors?

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Check MSDN (OR) search Google.

Comment: i have done some research on google.. but couldnot find a suitable answer, except this by adding a .cs file with your code, you can see compilation errors and can correct them otherwise these errors are shown at runtime.. which is of no good..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted from MSDN Documentation of [ASP.NET Web Page Code Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (little excerpt as outlined below)

> **Advantages of Code-Behind Pages**
>
> Code-behind pages offer advantages that make them suitable for Web
>   applications with significant code or in which multiple developers are
>   creating a Web site.
>
> Advantages of the code-behind model include the following:
>
> - Code-behind pages offer a clean separation of the markup (user    interface) and code.  It is practical to have a designer working on the markup while a programmer writes code.
> - Code is not exposed to page designers or others who are working only 
>        with the page markup.
> - Code can be reused for multiple pages.

Hope this gives you the idea behind having a separate code page model.

Comment: You are welcome. MSDN is the best resource when you want know something about .NET architecture.